# Unexpected result from PHP request

Tags: php, html

**I'm trying to build a small app which will notify me of changes in a website (my school's, actually) - it's HTML code modified**

I'm trying to get the HTML code of the following website.
http://www.tivon.ort.org.il/%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9-1/

I've tested serval ways to do this in PHP, including:

```
$html = file_get_contents(URL);
//OR
$html = file_get_html(URL); //Using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
```

As well as using cURL.

All these ways return the following HTML, which isn't the HTML of the page I'm trying to get:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><script src="//d1a702rd0dylue.cloudfront.net/js/iealml-03/10800.js"></script><script>window.rbzns = {}; rbzns.hosts="schools.ort.org.il www.achva.ort.org.il achva.ort.org.il acotech.ort.org.il afula.ort.org.il afulaalon.ort.org.il www.aliya2.ort.org.il aliya2.ort.org.il arad.ort.org.il www.astro.ort.org.il astro.ort.org.il www.bamaale.ort.org.il bamaale.ort.org.il www.bialik.ort.org.il bialik.ort.org.il dafna.ort.org.il eshkolakko.ort.org.il www.ganyavne.ort.org.il ganyavne.ort.org.il geha-edu.org.il www.geula.ort.org.il geula.ort.org.il www.givatayim.ort.org.il givatayim.ort.org.il givatram.ort.org.il www.guttman.ort.org.il guttman.ort.org.il www.hazor.ort.org.il hazor.ort.org.il hof-carmel.org.il www.hof-carmel.org.il www.holon.ort.org.il holon.ort.org.il www.igalalon.ort.org.il igalalon.ort.org.il www.kramim.ort.org.il kramim.ort.org.il www.lilienthal.ort.org.il lilienthal.ort.org.il lodtech.ort.org.il motzkin.ort.org.il neriya.ort.org.il www.orenafula.ort.org.il orenafula.ort.org.il www.ormat.ort.org.il ormat.ort.org.il www.oumbatin.ort.org.il oumbatin.ort.org.il www.psagot.ort.org.il psagot.ort.org.il www.rogozin.ort.org.il rogozin.ort.org.il www.sajur.ort.org.il sajur.ort.org.il sapirextra.ort.org.il www.shamir.ort.org.il www.sharet.ort.org.il shemer.ort.org.il www.spanian.ort.org.il spanian.ort.org.il tarshiha.ort.org.il technology.ort.org.il www.technology.ort.org.il www.tivon.ort.org.il tivon.ort.org.il www.ulpanit.ort.org.il ulpanit.ort.org.il www.yadshapira.ort.org.il yadshapira.ort.org.il www.yeshmaalot.ort.org.il yeshmaalot.ort.org.il yeshtveria.ort.org.il www.kugel.org.il roz.ort.org.il ylb.ort.org.il tzurarad.ort.org.il www.hilmi.ort.org.il oma.ort.org.il hauashle.ort.org.il vilnai.ort.org.il sheandati.ort.org.il ronsonc.ort.org.il afek.ort.org.il www.dekelvilnae.ort.org.il www.mevoot-eron.org yami-ashdod.ort.org.il www.sheanklali.ort.org.il molada.ort.org.il www.melton.ort.org.il www.sallama.ort.org.il www.telnof.ort.org.il ortlaaoc.ort.org.il www.shapira.ort.org.il www.bgg.co.il www.ebin.ort.org.il darski.ort.org.il www.iai.ort.org.il modiin.ort.org.il www.modiin.ort.org.il ortmodiin.ort.org.il neve-sara.ort.org.il ort-yadin.ort.org.il www.lod.ort.org.il"; rbzns.ctrbg="L2Pfvthe2b9jPQUWp0ZxIu248ov5v83+GtxsvLzg1jjDmPckhvTjr0FM3NAO4BEKVXI7AgAz1PMMI2MlLtJDnajFt+6HZ3Zi99Z55YvMvU8ardvckHHwI8/O+x3DhYi0YjF7irWG0sgbbUEDU6m8JdUZsvvzDHnJiVyP7XeiY+gpZM6WCIrZ+NhhuWfwAuvNS5UY6mazB+ZIhvkNA+RObxAUD5VHeqzh8WJIVFYorZ4RCohU28Q2jjbtKqHn7wdJ";rbzns.rbzreqid="2e6d1f6c31343232323037373231cb23df000c96b36c"; winsocks(true);</script></body></html>
```

I did manage to get the HTML code of other websites using the routes I've examined, but not of the particular site I actually need the HTML of.
From my understanding, it's somehow "protected" against bots.

Any way around this unnecessary "protection"? Hints?

Comment: Eran you need access to Ort's server. You can't get their PHP code you can get only plain HTML

Comment: I do want the HTML of their website, not the PHP

Comment: I will check it, one moment

Comment: On the face of it, from the point of view of the site administrator, this protection is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you visit the website for the first time, it sets a cookie `rbzid`. You have to remember this cookie. There's an example how to use curl with a cookiejar [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/cookiejar.html). They also remember your user-agent. I'm not sure if they also check that this user-agent is a browser - I don't think so, but they may. In any case, you have to keep the same user-agent. It's probably somehow encoded in the cookie.

You can verify this like this: open the website in your browser. Check the value of the rbzid cookie. Also copy the user-agent of your browser. Then, in a terminal, run this:

```
curl "http://www.tivon.ort.org.il/%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9-1/" -A "user-agent" --cookie rbzid=cookie
```