# Unexpected result from wget

Tags: perl, wget

I received strange result from URL:
http://banner.prestigecasino.com/download/casino/client_update_urls.php

If I use a browser - I get a result.

If I use perl *LWP::UserAgent* or *wget* - I get a strange output.

> ```
> wget http://banner.prestigecasino.com/download/casino/client_update_urls.php
> ```

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><script src="//d1a702rd0dylue.cloudfront.net/js/iealml-10-1/10800.js"></script><script>window.rbzns = 
{}; rbzns.challdomain=".prestigecasino.com"; rbzns.ctrbg="wGc4uoPOw9Z43y/mCXjboruSCfOcUOcHsILlHf2shF+Z1ygLZnvECWQy1JIbHMvSkIFkkQq7CKSrHCO3soSA9AM6dCX
SwL4Dot2zXoNeKndXwgSeBfFTc/ACeunbVu2nBbvQeR1+cNZBVwqjExNn8C5+uj0gk7vCm6h6GaiWgJI=";rbzns.rbzreqid="ovh-whg-reblazer531343336323632393134a750dc75b5199
690"; winsocks(true);</script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a bot detection script. It runs the script in there to untangle what you downloaded and verify you're using a (javascript aware) browser rather than e.g. LWP.

It's fairly common, especially for sites that you can 'play' via automation scripts more efficiently than you'd be able to in person.

Trick is if you 'run' the javascript, you probably get something that either renders the page, or redirects you to one, or sets a cookie or something similar. This means that the basic (WGET/LWP/WWW::Mechanize) based tools don't work.

See:

[Unexpected result from PHP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139457/unexpected-result-from-php-request)

For some further details on how this might work. This *particular* javascript appears  to set a cookie called `rbzid` which you may able to retrieve from your browser and then re-use within your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. 
Any idea how check content automatically with perl ?

Comment: The whole idea is to protect the content from automated retrieval. You can try to work around the WAF, but eventually it will be updated to detect your tricks and block it.